# Django: How to show only the data corresponding to the current user?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to develop a simple webpage in Django where the users shall be able to create databases via ModelForms and explore only their own created content. They shall not be able to see data created by other users. So far I was not able to realize that, each user is still able to see the data of all other users.

In my models.py I linked my database to the User by Foreign Key. 
I think the problem lies in my view.py  but I am somehow stuck..

I would be grateful for any help. 
Thank you in advance!

This is my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

CHOICES = (
    ('rent', 'Rent'), 
    ('grocery', 'Grocery'), 
    ('shopping', 'Shopping'), 
    ('gym', 'Gym'), 
    ('phone', 'Phone'), 
    ('freetime', 'Freetime'), 
    ('other', 'Other')
)

class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="new_spending", null=True)   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    expense_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=CHOICES)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from datetime import date
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import UserDetails


class UserModelForm(ModelForm):
    current_date = date.today()
    YEARS = [x for x in range(current_date.year - 1, current_date.year + 6)]
    today = current_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    date_added = forms.DateField(initial=today, widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=YEARS))

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        fields = ['title', 'notes', 'expense_name', 'cost', 'date_added', 'category']
```

My **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import models
from .models import UserDetails
from .forms import UserModelForm

def userDetails(request):         

    if request.method == 'POST':   
        form = UserModelForm(request.POST)    
        if form.is_valid():
            u = form.save()

            users = UserDetails.objects.all()
            request.user.new_spending.add(u) 

            return render(request, 'budget_app/display.html', {        
                'users': users
                })

    else:
        form_class = UserModelForm

        return render(request, 'budget_app/userdetails.html', {
            'form': form_class,
            })
```

My **html file**:

```
{% extends 'budget_app/budget_base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<head>
<style>
table {
  width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #fff;
}
table#t01 th {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

</br>
<h2>Your Spending History</h2>
</br>

<table id="t01">

  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>gender</th>
    <th>Notes</th>
    <th>Expense name</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Category</th>
  </tr>

  {% for item in users %}

  <tr>

    <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.gender|default:"NA" }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.notes }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.expense_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.cost }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.date_added }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<br>

</body>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

to restrict the details that a user can see, you should pass the objects that are filtered to be related to that user only.

"UserDetails.objects.all()" should be like this:
UserDetails.objects.filter(user= request.user)

Comment: Thank you Mahdi, the filter method solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to select just the current user details with  a queryset like:

users = request.user.new_spending.all()